# Probability that there will be no mutual best friendships?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, probability

Here is a problem:

> There are two groups of n users, 'A' and 'B'. Each user in A is friends with those in B, and vice versa. Each user in A will randomly choose a user in B as their best friend and each user in B will randomly choose a user in A as their best friend. If two people have chosen each other, they are *mutual best friends*. **What is the probability that there will be no mutual best friendships?**

I thought about the problem this way:
Consider the sample space $\Omega$ consisting of a couple of functions $(f,g)$ $f: A \longrightarrow B$ and $g: B \longrightarrow A$ and enumerate $(f,g)$ such that for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ $f(a) \ne b$ or $g(b) \ne a$.

I end up with the following formula: $1-\frac{\sum_{0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k}^2 k^k}{n^{2n}}$ (which I think cannot be more simplified nor correct).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Bass It is not derangements since there is no restriction that people choose distinct best friends. The mappings $f$ and $g$ are not necessarily permutations.

Comment: @Bass derangement was my answer too, and I wrote it here (now I deleted it). Until I realized that even though "no mutual best friend" iff "there is a derangement on composite function $g(f(x))$", it's not a bijection. One derangement leads to a non-trivial number of "no mutual best friend" configuration. And based on my simulation, the number of non-mutual config $z(n)$ is: $z(1)=0, z(2)=2, z(3)=156, z(4)=16920, z(5)=2764880$. (so OP formula is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Among all $n^{2n}$ function pairs $(f,g)$, you want to count the ones that avoid all $n^2$ properties $f(a)=b \land g(b)=a$.  This is a job for the inclusion-exclusion principle.

See https://oeis.org/A284458, where the inclusion-exclusion formula is given:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2 k! n^{2(n-k)}$$

Divide by $n^{2n}$ to get the probability:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2 k! n^{-2k}$$